# pandas for each group return rows that bigger from the first

Tags: python, pandas

I have df the sort according to date and group that looks like that:

```
id  date   money
1     1.1    20
1     2.1    50
2     5.1    20
2     6.1    10
3     8.9    70
3     10.9   90
```

I want to return a df that contains rows that the dates in which the money of a id was greater than the revenue on their first day.
so the desire df is:

```
id  date  money
1    2.1    50
3    10.9    90
```

I tried:

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('id').first()
```

but not sure how to select those rows.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform('first')` to populate the first values to all rows so that you can compare:

```
first_values = df.sort_values('date').groupby('id')['money'].transform('first')
df[df['money'] > first_values]
```

Output:

```
   id  date  money
1   1   2.1     50
5   3  10.9     90
```

Comment: I get an error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: is `id` your index?

Comment: I applied group by and sort values by date in order to get for each id dates follow in time

Comment: I used  ` df[df['money'] > first_values.reset_index(drop=True] ` and its works.thx